# Null space of a linear functional has co-dimension 1

Tags: functional-analysis

From a proof that the non-trivial null space of a linear functional has co-dimension 1:

$L$ is a linear space, $L_f$ is a subspace of $L$ and is a null space of a linear functional $f$. It's necessary to prove that $L/ L_f$ has dimension 1. The part of the proof:

Let $x_0\in L/L_f$ and so $f(x_0)\neq 0$. For an arbitrary $x\in L$ we can write
$$
x = \frac{f(x)}{f(x_0)}\cdot x_0 + y \quad\quad (1)
$$
and then $f(y)=f(x-\frac{f(x)}{f(x_0)}\cdot x_0)=0$, i.e. $y\in L_f$.

Question: Why can we write equation (1)? In particular, why do we have a multiplier $f(x)/f(x_0)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to choose a scalar $c$ such that $f(x-cx_0)=0$ so that $y=x-cx_0$ is in the kernel of $f$. This can be done by choosing $c$ such that $f(x)-cf(x_0)=0$ or $c =\frac {f(x)} {f(x_0)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=x-\dfrac{f(x)}{f(x_{0})}\cdot x_{0}$, then you have that and $f(y)=f(x)-\dfrac{f(x)}{f(x_{0})}\cdot f(x_{0})=f(x)-f(x)=0$.