# Does $V^* \otimes V^* \cong L(V, V; K)$ hold when $V$ is infinite dimensional?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra, dual-spaces

Let $V$ be a $K$–vector space, let $V^*$ be its (algebraic) dual space, and let $L(V, V; K)$ denote the space of bilinear maps from $V \times V \to K$.

Does $V^* \otimes V^* \cong L(V, V; K)$ hold when $V$ is infinite dimensional? If so, please give a proof using the universal property.

[By $\cong$, I mean not only vector space isomorphism, but isomorphism as tensor product spaces over $V^* \times V^*$. The "natural" multilinear map from $V^* \times V^* \to L(V, V; K)$ is the one taking $(\omega_1, \omega_2) \mapsto \omega_1(\cdot)\omega_2(\cdot)$. I'm asking whether $L(V, V; K)$ along with this multilinear map is a tensor product space over $V^* \times V^*$, in the sense of satisfying the universal property.]

If $V$ is finite dimensional, then this isomorphism and several related isomorphisms hold. I know that in general, these isomorphisms rely on $V \simeq V^*$, which only holds when $V$ is finite dimensional. However, the "unary" version of the above identity, $V^* \simeq L(V; K)$ holds (by definition) regardless of the dimension of $V$, and if the "binary" version above holds, it would be a nice way to see why $V \otimes V \simeq L(V^*, V^*; K)$ also holds in (and only in) the finite dimensional case (using $V \simeq V^{**})$.

My approach was to consider the map $\phi: V^* \times V^* \to L(V, V; K)$ defined by $\phi(\omega_1,\omega_2)(v_1, v_2) = \omega_1(v_1) \omega_2(v_2)$. Then $\phi$ is multilinear, so the universal property gives a linear map $\tilde\phi : V^* \otimes V^* \to L(V, V; K)$ such that $\phi = \tilde\phi \circ \otimes$. If we can show $\tilde\phi$ is an isomorphism, we are done. But I can't show this, and don't even know if it is true.

Comment: By $\cong$, are you simply referring to vector space isomorphism?

Comment: Let $V$ be the space of bounded infinite sequences of real numbers and consider the functional on $V \times V$ given by $(x_n, y_n) \mapsto \sum x_ny_n/n^2$, the infinite sum converging by the boundedness of the sequences.  I believe this functional is not in the image of your map. (I don't know how to prove it.)

Comment: @BenGrossmann No, I mean isomorphic as tensor product spaces. I'll modify the post to clarify this.

Comment: (Your map is an iso in the f.d. case because you can check injectivity and then count dimensions. In the infinite dimensional case it seems like you want to impose some topology and take a completed tensor product. But again I don't know the proof that the ugly thing I wrote down isn't in the image.)

Comment: @hunter  Needs proof.  $V$ is infinite-dimensional, then (according to AC) $V^*$ contains a lot of  linear functionals, not just the ones expressible in terms of the coordinates of the sequence.

Comment: @WillG I'm not sure what the distinction is between an isomorphism of tensor product spaces and an ordinary linear isomorphism between tensor product spaces

Comment: @BenGrossmann Another way to phrase my question is, "Is $L(V, V; K)$ (along with the natural multilinear map $V^* \times V^* \to L(V, V; K)$ described in the post) a tensor product space over $V^* \times V^*$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your map may fail to be surjective. So, I suspect the isomorphism does not hold.

Let $V$ denote the space of real sequences with at most finitely many elements. Let $\alpha \in L(V,V; K)$ denote the map
$$
\alpha[(x_1,x_2,\dots),(y_1,y_2,\dots)] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty x_ky_k.
$$
I claim that this cannot be expressed as a finite sum of the form $\alpha = \sum_{k=1}^n \omega_1^{(k)} \otimes \omega_2^{(k)}$.

Suppose for the purpose of contradiction that such a decomposition of $\alpha$ exists. We can assume without loss of generality that the $\omega_i^{(k)}$ are linearly independent (and thus have distinct kernels). The functionals $\omega_1^{(k)}$ each have one-dimensional cokernels. It follows that the quotient space
$$
V/(\ker(\omega_1^{(1)}) \cap  \cdots \cap \ker(\omega_1^{(n)})) \cong 
V/\ker(\omega_1^{(1)}) \oplus \cdots \oplus V/\ker(\omega_1^{(n)})
$$
is also finite dimensional. Thus, $\ker(\omega_1^{(1)}) \cap  \cdots \cap \ker(\omega_1^{(n)})$ must be infinite dimensional. Select any non-zero $x \in \ker(\omega_1^{(1)}) \cap  \cdots \cap \ker(\omega_1^{(n)})$. From the decomposition of $\alpha$, we find that $\alpha(x,y) = 0$ holds for all $y$ in $V$. However, this clearly does not hold for our $\alpha$ as it was originally defined; for instance, we can see that $\alpha(x,x) \neq 0$ will hold for all non-zero $x$ (for other fields, take $y$ equal to the standard basis elements of $V$). Thus, we have reached a contradiction.

Comment: Why do the functionals $\omega_1^{(k)}$ have one-dimensional cokernels?

Comment: @WillG See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3455432/81360) for instance